# How to make a excel cell content encrypted while typing into the cell?

Tags: excel

I have a requirement, where i keep few user passwords in excel cells and then use these data pragmatically for automation purposes. Since password should not be seen to others, i want these to typed as ****** or $$$$$ anything like this, but when i read the cell via program it should fetch the real password.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent Excel from displaying the clear password during the typing, as the formula bar will always show you the unencrypted content.

Two workarounds options:

1.) Hide the formula, so that the user can only see his input directly in the cell. Give this cell a custom format `"*******"`. Now, after entering the password, only stars will be displayed.

Note that this is not secure at all - while typing, the user can still see the password. and when editing the cell, the user will see the password! Therefore, this is only feasible, if you want a user to not see the password at a first glance!

2.) Insert an ActiveX textbox. In the properties of this textbox, set `*` as `PasswordChar`. If you want to use the password in other Excel formulas, also link it to a hidden cell. If you only want to access the password programmatically, you can use `Sheets("YourSheetName").OLEObjects("YourTextboxName").Object.Value`

Comment: I 2nd the 2nd option here. Hiding formula bar has it's quirks, because 1) user can see password when entered and also anyone can access the cell to get the information, unless you wrap some vba functionality around it. All the extra work is not worth it. ActiveX textbox with password character is the way to go. Possibly even better is a userform that stores the password into a variable.